# How to do this in Laravel, subquery where in

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, subquery

How can I make this query in Laravel:

```
SELECT 
    `p`.`id`,
    `p`.`name`, 
    `p`.`img`, 
    `p`.`safe_name`, 
    `p`.`sku`, 
    `p`.`productstatusid` 
FROM `products` p 
WHERE `p`.`id` IN (
    SELECT 
        `product_id` 
    FROM `product_category`
    WHERE `category_id` IN ('223', '15')
)
AND `p`.`active`=1
```

I could also do this with a join, but I need this format for performance.

Answer (score 278, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
Products::whereIn('id', function($query){
    $query->select('paper_type_id')
    ->from(with(new ProductCategory)->getTable())
    ->whereIn('category_id', ['223', '15'])
    ->where('active', 1);
})->get();
```

Comment: Accepted this answer, question is out of date as it was concerning Laravel 3, and the answers coming in are for Laravel 4, answer below will work for 4 aswell.

Comment: @lukaserat the query in question is applying the      AND `p`.`active`=1
 check on products tables whereas your query is applying it to table of ProductCategory....right?? or is there something I am missing..?

Comment: @hhsadiq yes, it is referring to ProductCategory.

Comment: Nice approach with the table name. It's a plus for me

Comment: Work fine for laravel 5.5

Answer (score 88):

Have a look at the [advanced where clause documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#advanced-where-clauses) for Fluent. Here's an example of what you're trying to achieve:

```php
DB::table('users')
    ->whereIn('id', function($query)
    {
        $query->select(DB::raw(1))
              ->from('orders')
              ->whereRaw('orders.user_id = users.id');
    })
    ->get();
```

This will produce:

```sql
select * from users where id in (
    select 1 from orders where orders.user_id = users.id
)
```

Comment: That comes close, and i've been puzzeling with similar queries for some time now. But where_in (laravel 3) requires 2 arguments, the second one being an array. Any idea how to get this right? Also, I don't think laravel 3 supports the from method.

Comment: Ah, Laravel3... Yeah, that's going to be difficult then.  And I think in Laravel3 you use the `table()` method instead of the `from()`.  I haven't had that situation in L3, sorry!

Comment: I can't see a whereIn method which takes a lambda in Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder has it been renamed whereSub?

Answer (score 26):

You can use variable by using keyword "use ($category_id)"

```
$category_id = array('223','15');
Products::whereIn('id', function($query) use ($category_id){
   $query->select('paper_type_id')
     ->from(with(new ProductCategory)->getTable())
     ->whereIn('category_id', $category_id )
     ->where('active', 1);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 15):

Here is my approach for **Laravel 8.x** gathered from multiple answers here:

- Use the query builder and don't write SQL directly.
- Use the models and determine everything from there. Don't use a hardcoded table name, or any name (columns, and so on) for that matter.

```
Product::select(['id', 'name', 'img', 'safe_name', 'sku', 'productstatusid'])
    ->whereIn('id', ProductCategory::select(['product_id'])
        ->whereIn('category_id', ['223', '15'])
    )
    ->where('active', 1)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use Eloquent in different queries and make things easier to understand and mantain:

```
$productCategory = ProductCategory::whereIn('category_id', ['223', '15'])
                   ->select('product_id'); //don't need ->get() or ->first()
```

and then we put all together:

```
Products::whereIn('id', $productCategory)
          ->where('active', 1)
          ->select('id', 'name', 'img', 'safe_name', 'sku', 'productstatusid')
          ->get();//runs all queries at once
```

This will generate the same query that you wrote in your question.

Answer (score 9):

The script is tested in Laravel 5.x and 6.x. The `static` closure can improve performance in some cases.

```
Product::select(['id', 'name', 'img', 'safe_name', 'sku', 'productstatusid'])
            ->whereIn('id', static function ($query) {
                $query->select(['product_id'])
                    ->from((new ProductCategory)->getTable())
                    ->whereIn('category_id', [15, 223]);
            })
            ->where('active', 1)
            ->get();
```

generates the SQL

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `img`, `safe_name`, `sku`, `productstatusid` FROM `products` 
WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `product_id` FROM `product_category` WHERE 
`category_id` IN (?, ?)) AND `active` = ?
```

Comment: Is there any way to use a scope of ProductCategory?

Comment: @SergeiKrivosheenko Yes, look at my answer to this question.

Answer (score 6):

The following code worked for me:

```
$result=DB::table('tablename')
->whereIn('columnName',function ($query) {
                $query->select('columnName2')->from('tableName2')
                ->Where('columnCondition','=','valueRequired');

            })
->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 4.2 and beyond, may use try relationship querying:-

```
Products::whereHas('product_category', function($query) {
$query->whereIn('category_id', ['223', '15']);
});

public function product_category() {
return $this->hasMany('product_category', 'product_id');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Product::from('products as p')
->join('product_category as pc','p.id','=','pc.product_id')
->select('p.*')
->where('p.active',1)
->whereIn('pc.category_id', ['223', '15'])
->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

using a variable

```
$array_IN=Dev_Table::where('id',1)->select('tabl2_id')->get();
$sel_table2=Dev_Table2::WhereIn('id',$array_IN)->get();
```

Comment: This will result in two querys and not just one. You can insert the first query builder into the second one, without getting the result of the first quary. See Philipes answer for more details.

Answer (score -1):

You use `DB::raw` to set subquery.

Example

```
DB::raw('(
    SELECT 
    `product_id` 
    FROM `product_category`
    WHERE `category_id` IN ('223', '15') as `product_id`
')
```

Answer (score -4):

Please try this online tool [sql2builder](https://sql2builder.github.io/)

```
DB::table('products')
    ->whereIn('products.id',function($query) {
                            DB::table('product_category')
                            ->whereIn('category_id',['223','15'])
                            ->select('product_id');
                        })
    ->where('products.active',1)
    ->select('products.id','products.name','products.img','products.safe_name','products.sku','products.productstatusid')
    ->get();
```