# How can I do subqueries in Laravel's fluent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Say I have this bit of SQL:

```
select * 
from `fluents`
inner join `tests` on `fluents`.`id` = `tests`.`fluent_test_id`
inner join (
    select `fluents`.`id` from `fluents` order by `fluents`.`id` desc limit 10
) as j on `fluents`.`id` = `j`.`id`
order by `fluents`.`created_at`;
```

I know I could run the raw SQL but as a learning exercise I'm trying to convert it to fluent and failing miserably, is this even possible?

Comment: use DB::query($sql) for laravel fluent to execute query.

Comment: I mean't using the query builder, not just simply executing the raw SQL.

Comment: ok Are you using laravel 3 or 4?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do this in Laravel, subquery where in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815551/how-to-do-this-in-laravel-subquery-where-in)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have done it this way in my project:

```
DB::table('fluents')->join('tests','tests.fluent_test_id','=','fluents.id')
                    ->join(DB::raw("(select fluents.id from fluents order by `fluents`.`id` desc limit 10) as j"),'j.id','=','fluents.id')
                    ->orderBy('fluents.created_at');
```

I hope this can be of some help.