# Raw query to Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have polymorphic many-to-many relation between my projects and (members, teams) tables. Basically a member or a team can be assigned to a project. And members are grouped under teams.

I want to select projects which are assigned to the team that current member is in. I can get it by raw query like this:

```
DB::select(
  DB::raw('
    SELECT DISTINT project_id FROM projectvisibles PV 
      WHERE PV.projectvisible_type = "Team" 
        AND PV.projectvisible_id IN (
          SELECT team_id FROM member_team 
            WHERE member_id = :id)
  '), ['id' => $id]
);
```

How can i write this raw query in Eloquent form?

My DB:

**Projects table:**

> id,
>   project_id,
>   name

**Members Table:**

> id,
>   name

**Teams Table:**

> id,
>   name

**Member_Team Table:** *(members can be grouped under teams, via this table)*

> member_id,
>   team_id

**ProjectVisibles Table:**
 *(projects can be assigned to members OR teams via this table (polymorphic many-to-many)*

> project_id,
>   projectvisible_id *(member id or team id)*,
>   projectvisible_type *(member or team)*

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815551/how-to-do-this-in-laravel-subquery-where-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be something this kind

```
Db::table('projectvisibles')->where('projectvisible_type', '=', 'Team')->whereIn('projectvisible_id', function($query) use (& $id)
{
    $query->select('team_id')->from('member_team')->where('member_id', '=', $id);
})->get();
```