# Using Laravel query builder method whereIn() with sub query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder, where-in

I am developing a Web Application using Laravel 5.3. I am now having an issue with Laravel query builder method, `whereIn`.

I have table like this.

```
student - id, name, dob
course - id, code
student_course -  student_id, course_id
```

What I want to do is I want to get students searching by `course_id` of student_course table without joining any table. In manual query, I do like this.

```
SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE `student`.`id` IN (SELECT `student_id` FROM `student_course` WHRE `course_id`= ?)
```

So now when I try to convert it into Laravel query builder, I have a problem. Here is my code:

```
DB::table('student')->whereIn('id',[ "Here I want to run sub query" ])->get();
```

As you can see in the second parameter of `whereIn()`, I get problem. In this scenario, do I need to run raw query? How can I run raw query as second parameter? If not, how can I filter by `course_id` just in one query like above and not joining to any table?

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815551/how-to-do-this-in-laravel-subquery-where-in

Comment: Yes that link solved my issue. Thanks so much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do this in Laravel, subquery where in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815551/how-to-do-this-in-laravel-subquery-where-in)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

refer this

```
 $courseId = 1;

 $data = DB::table('student')->whereIn('id',function($query) use (courseId){
    $query->select('student_id')
            ->from('student_course')->where('course_id', '=',$courseId);
})->get();
```

Comment: worth noting - if you don't use `from(...)` in the subquery, it will query the same table. So in this case `$query->from('student_course')...`

Answer (score 1):

If you want pass through model, you can use:

```
$res = Student::whereIn('id',StudentCourse::where('course_id',$course_id)->pluck('student_id')->toArray())->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
DB::table('student')
    ->whereRaw("id IN (SELECT `student_id` FROM `student_course` WHERE `course_id`= ?)", [$course_id])
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

for who one use query builder:

```
$data = DB::table('student')
->whereIn('id',DB::table('student_course')
->where('course_id','=',$courseId)
->pluck('student_id')
->toArray())
->get();
```