# Laravel Query Builder use parent query in subquery of `whereIn` statement?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

Laravel 8.x

I'm trying to do something like mentioned over [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/sub-query-wherein-from-existing-query)

(code copied from above link- minor change to comment)

```
$total = OrderTotals::whereIn('order_id', function($q) use($query) {
   // here would like to use the query of the parent instead of an empty fresh query
})->sum('value);
```

Where I would like to use the previous query in the subquery when calling `->whereIn` is this possible how can I do this?

The `$query` variable in the closure is empty and produces a `select *` without any from or wheres. This make sense since a subquery can be wanted to be fresh. But what if I would like to use the existing query?

I used [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=laravel%20query%20builder%20wherein%20subquery%20using%20parent%20query&safe=strict&rlz=1C1SQJL_en&ei=3m62YI3AIMi0ggfF4ZZ4&oq=laravel%20query%20builder%20wherein%20subquery%20using%20p&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMYADIFCCEQoAEyBQghEKABMgUIIRCgATIFCCEQqwIyBQghEKsCMgUIIRCrAjoHCAAQRxCwAzoCCAA6BggAEBYQHjoHCCEQChCgAVCiHFjhQWDASGgBcAJ4AIABkgGIAfsQkgEEMjAuNZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz) google search among many others to find a similar question. The results on stackoverflow don't seem to use the existing query, they all add new `from`s and `where`s (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40860232/using-laravel-query-builder-method-wherein-with-sub-query) and [this highly rated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815551/how-to-do-this-in-laravel-subquery-where-in)).

Comment: from what I understood you need the OrderTotals that their order_id is in [...] and u want to have the total of them if some condition is met .

Comment: I want where their order_id is in a subquery not and array. If I do whereIn and pass a closure then that's a subquery. The problem is that I want the subquery to be the parent query but a whereIn doesn't give you handle to the parent query only to a fresh query.

Comment: i think my answer can help you, look at second part

Answer (score 0):

See if something like this helps

```
Model::where(function($query)
{
    $query->whereIn('order_id', [1,2,3]);

    //OR

    $query->or_where('order_id', function(){
         // do something
    });

})->where('other condition')->sum('value');
```

this may also work  :

```
OrderTotals::addSelect(['order_id' => Order::select('id')
    ->whereColumn('active', 0)
    ->orderByDesc('completed_at')
])->sum();
```