# Laravel Query builder table join

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I've a requirement to convert this to Laravel Query Builder:

Raw SQL:

```
Select * from requests where user_id in (select user_id from profiles where total_sales <= 10);
```

This is my Query builder:

```
public static function apply(Builder $builder, $value)
{
 return $builder->where('user_id', function($query) use ($value) {
        $query->where('profiles.total_sales','<=',$value);
    });
}
```

This is not working. What am I missing?

PS: This is a portion of large dynamic query and this is the portion that is not working so, I'm posting only this portion of the query.

Comment: what is not working? do you get error message? anyway, you need sub-query, your example is just adding 2 **where** conditions

Comment: maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815551/how-to-do-this-in-laravel-subquery-where-in) could point you in the right direction

Comment: @ljubadr, yes, I get error:  QueryException

SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: SELECT * with no tables specified is not valid
LINE 1: ...regate from "requests" where "user_id" in (select * where "p...
^ (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from "requests" where "user_id" in (select * where "profiles"."total_sales" <= 5))

Comment: You should add error message to queston

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the query with help from link provided by @ljubadr :

```
public static function apply(Builder $builder, $value){ return $builder->whereIn('user_id', function($query){
            $query->select('user_id')
                ->from(with(new UserProfile)->getTable())
                ->where('profiles.total_sale','<', 1);
        });
```

}

Thank you @ljubadr.