# Laravel Eloquent equivalent of MYSQL IN

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I got two tables. I want to get all users and their details who are active/banned.

**What is laravel eloquent equivalent to this query.**

```
  'select * from client_details where user_id IN (select user_id from client_logins where is_active='.$active.')'
```

Table: **client_logins** Model clientLogin

```
+---------+---------+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| id      | user_id |  username    | password    | is_active |
+---------+---------+--------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Table: **client_details** Model clientDetail

```
+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| user_id | name | email | mobile |  address|
+---------+------+-------+------------------+
```

Comment: Anything you have tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do this in Laravel, subquery where in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815551/how-to-do-this-in-laravel-subquery-where-in)

Comment: is `user_id` in client_details a primary key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using query builder you could write it as

```
$clients=DB::table('client_details as c')
                ->select('c.*')
                ->join('client_logins as l', 'c.user_id', '=', 'l.user_id')
                ->where('l.is_active', '=', $active)
                ->get()
;
```

Or if have defined `has` relation for `ClientDetails` model you can use `whereHas` filter

```
class ClientDetails extends Model
{

    public function client_logins()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ClientLogins', 'user_id', 'user_id');
    }
}

$clients = ClientDetails::whereHas('client_logins', function ($query) use ($active)  {
    $query->where('is_active', '=', $active);
})->get();
```