# Inner query in where clause laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have a database in which there are two tables `driver_company_map` and `company` what i do is i get `company_code` from `driver_company_map` table and i pass it in the where clause of another query which i perform on `company` table my both separate query works like this

```
$result = DB::connection($this->masterDb)->table('driver_company_map')
        ->where('driver_code', $driverCode) //i get the $driverCode from function parameter
        ->select('company_code')
        ->first();
        $companyCode = $result->company_code;
```

I use the above `$companyCode` in the below query

```
$result = DB::connection($this->masterDb)->table('company')
        ->where('code', $companyCode)
        ->select('db_connection')
        ->first();
        $clientDb = $result->db_connection;
```

The above logic works fine but i want both as nested query i tried it but not giving the correct result below is my code

```
$result = DB::connection($this->masterDb)->table('company')
        ->where('code', function($companyCode_query){
            $companyCode_query->select('company_code')
            ->from('driver_company_map')
            >where('driver_code', $driverCode);
        })->get()
        ->select('db_connection')
        ->first();
        $clientDb = $result->db_connection;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I guess you can find solution for your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815551/how-to-do-this-in-laravel-subquery-where-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = DB::connection($this->masterDb)->table('company')
    ->select('db_connection')
    ->join('driver_company_map', 'company.code', 'driver_company_map.company_code')
    ->where('driver_company_map.driver_code', $driverCode)
    ->first();
```

Refer to this:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins

Comment: Thanks you the answer is correct just one mistake `$result = DB::connection($this->masterDb)->table('company')
    ->select('db_connection')
    ->join('driver_company_map', 'company.code', 'driver_company_map.company_code')
    ->where('driver_company_map.driver_code', $driverCode)
    ->first();` `driver_company_map.driver_code` will come instead of this `driver_company_map.company_code`