# How to implement nested MySQL query in Laravel Eloquent using Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.6

This is my MySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM cc_calenders 
WHERE 
   cc_calenders.user_id = 1 
OR 
   cc_calenders.id = (
           SELECT cc_calender_shares.calender_id 
           FROM cc_calender_shares 
           WHERE 
                cc_calender_shares.shared_with = 'epsita@matrixnmedia.com')
```

I tried to write the Laravel eloquent code like this:

```
$records    = Calender::where('user_id', $user_id)
                        ->orWhere('id', function($query) use ($user_email) {
                                $query->table('calender_shares')
                                      ->select('calender_shares.calender_id')
                                      ->where('calender_shares.shared_with', $user_email);
                        })->get();
```

I am getting this error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::table()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do this in Laravel, subquery where in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815551/how-to-do-this-in-laravel-subquery-where-in)

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$records    = Calender::where('user_id', $user_id)
                        ->orWhere('id', function($query) use ($user_email) {
                                $query->select('calender_id')
                                      ->from('calender_shares')
                                      ->where('shared_with', $user_email);
                        })->get();
```

[How to do this in Laravel, subquery where in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815551/how-to-do-this-in-laravel-subquery-where-in)

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody could answer me before I get my own answer, I am putting the code down here for people who might stumble on same problem.

The main issue was, I was using table() function in the subquery. The better solution was to use from() function.

The code snippet `from(with(new CalenderShare)->getTable())` would provide me a the table name of model CalenderShare.

```
Calender::where('user_id', $user_id)
          ->orWhereIn('id', function($query) use ($user_email) {
                               $query->from(with(new CalenderShare)->getTable())
                                       ->select('calender_shares.calender_id')
                                       ->where('calender_shares.shared_with', $user_email);
                            })->get();
```