# Insert query inside query in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel-5

I have this function on my controller to print a monthly report. The report displays the balance from months before and display transaction inputs and outputs units from stocks in certain month.

I've tried query transactions in this month, but I can't insert balance's query from months before into one table.

```php
public function p_report(Request $request) {
    $report = DB::table('unit as u')
    ->select('u.id','name_u',
        'price',
        DB::raw('sum(qty_in) vol_in'),
        DB::raw('sum(price*qty_in) qty_ins'),
        DB::raw('sum(qty_out) vol_out'),
        DB::raw('sum(price*qty_out) qty_outs'),
        DB::raw('sum(qty_in)-sum(qty_out) vol_end'),
        DB::raw('sum(price*qty_in)-sum(price*qty_out)qty_end')
        )
    ->leftJoin('transaction as t', 't.unit_id', '=', 'u.id')
    ->where('status',1)
    ->where('type_unit', '=' , $request->type_unit)
    ->whereMonth('date_transaction','=', $request->month)
    ->whereYear('date_transaction', '=' , $request->year)
    ->groupBy(['u.id','name_u','price'])
    ->orderBy('name_u')
    ->get();

    foreach ($report as $reports) {
        $balance = DB::table('unit as u')
       ->select(
          DB::raw('sum(price*qty_in)-sum(price*qty_out) qty_balance')
          )
       ->leftJoin('transaction as t', 't.unit_id', '=', 'u.id')
       ->where('u.id', '=' , $reports->id)
       ->whereMonth('date_transaction','<', $request->month)
       ->whereYear('date_transaction', '=' , $request->year)
       ->get();
        $reports->qty_balance = $balance;
     }

    return view ('report/p_report', compact('report','balance','reports'));
}
```

Can I insert a query into another query to be single table? I have tried, but the result like this, I want qty_balance display a value not inside Collection like this:

```
    Collection {#247 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => {#245 ▼
      +"id": 3
      +"name_unit": "Folio"
      +"price": 40000
      +"vol_in": "81"
      +"qty_ins": "3240000"
      +"vol_out": "16"
      +"qty_outs": "640000"
      +"vol_end": "65"
      +"qty_end": "2600000"
      +"qty_balance": Collection {#262 ▶}
    }
    1 => {#246 ▼
      +"id": 5
      +"name_unit": "Pulpen"
      +"price": 50000
      +"vol_in": "100"
      +"qty_ins": "5000000"
      +"vol_out": "23"
      +"qty_outs": "1150000"
      +"vol_end": "77"
      +"qty_end": "3850000"
      +"qty_balance": Collection {#267 ▶}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: unable to understand your query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use:

- selectRaw https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/adding-a-subquery-to-an-eloquent-query
- SubQueries [How to do this in Laravel, subquery where in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815551/how-to-do-this-in-laravel-subquery-where-in)
- Or pure SQL (inside Model)

Don't make sense "fusing" queries, I think.