# Select from select using Laravel eloquent

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I want to get all user's favourite products. The query should be like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM favourites WHERE user_id == Auth::id())
```

How can I query with eloquent?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815551/how-to-do-this-in-laravel-subquery-where-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to achieve something like this:

In the oficial documentation you can find the explanation of [Advanced where clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#advanced-where-clauses)

```
DB::table('products')
    ->whereIn('id', function($query)
        {
            $query->select('id')
                  ->from('favourites')
                  ->where('favourites.user_id', Auth::id());
        })
    ->get()
```

The final result will be (you can see this dumping the query using toSql() method instead of get()) :

```
select * from `products` where `id` in (select `id` from `favourites` where `favourites`.`user_id` = ?)
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean to saying "How can I do it"? Are you asking how to structure it or how to query with eloquent?

If you asking the query:

```
Product::whereIn('id', Favourite::select('id')->whereUserId(Auth::id())->get()->toArray())->get();
```

should work.

---

If you asking structure, you should define relations in models.

On User model;

```
public function favourites()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Favourite::class, 'user_id');
}
```

and on Favourite model;

```
public function favoriteProduct()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, '[the product_id column on favourites table]');
}
```

and then you can access like;

```
$userFavourites = User::with('favourites.favoriteProduct')->whereId(Auth::id())->favourites;
```

on your view:

```
@foreach($userFavourites as $userFavourite)
    {{ $userFavourite->favouriteProduct }}
@endforeach
```

this is the simplest. on the other hand; you can use [Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship.

And this would be the cleanest way.

Comment: Product::whereIn('id', Favourite::select('id')->whereUserId(Auth::id())->get()->toArray())->get(); This is not a subselect. Imagine if subselect will give you 10.000 records, you will load them into array in php?