# How to pass external array to the query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, select, where-in

I am new to the mysql queries, i have one query which will search all the items inside the array `status in ('php','laravel','apiato')` if i use like this it's working, now i have to add more values to the array instead of passing strings i made one constant file from that file i want to send an array,it's throwing an exception `Array To string Conversion`

```
public function getALlData(){
$array = BooksConstants::Status_constants;
DB::select("SELECT count(1) as total_transactions from books  where books.account_id in ('$this->account_ids') and DATE(created_at) between ? and ? and status in $array ", [$fromDate, $toDate]);
}
```

Comment: What it return  print_r($array)

Comment: @KeerthiS $array=('php','laravel');

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do this in Laravel, subquery where in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815551/how-to-do-this-in-laravel-subquery-where-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we use `implode()` to convert array to string then inside `array_map()` function use `trim()` function to remove whitespaces. The `array_map()` function sends each value of an array to a user-made function.

```
public function getALlData()
{
    $array = BooksConstants::Status_constants;
    DB::select(
        "SELECT count(1) as total_transactions
         from books
         where books.account_id in ('$this->account_ids')
             and DATE(created_at) between ? and ?
             and status in ('" . implode("','", array_map('trim', $array)) ."') ",
        [$fromDate, $toDate]
    );
}
```

Comment: still getting Array to Conversion error and it's making an ` 'php,laravel,apiato' ` into one string

Comment: can you please little bit brief about the answer

Comment: First we use implode to convert array to string then inside array_map function use trim function to remove white spaces.... and then use  array_map() function its sends each value of an array to a user-made function