# How to write subqueries in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, orm

I am very new to the laravel subqueries , i am trying to fetch another table data  but it's showing an following error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT tl_titlename FROM bm_titlelist WHERE tl_titleid=1 from `bm_customercon...' at line 1 (SQL: select SELECT tl_titlename FROM bm_titlelist WHERE tl_titleid=1 from `bm_customercontactinfo`)
```

**query**

```
   DB::enableQueryLog();
        $data = DB::table('bm_customercontactinfo')
                    ->select(
                            DB::raw("SELECT tl_titlename FROM bm_titlelist WHERE tl_titleid=1")
                    )
                    ->get();
        dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

can anyone help me where did i mistake ?

Comment: Your Laravel logic does not make much sense.  Can you edit your question and include the raw MySQL query which you are trying to achieve in Laravel?

Comment: Check I hope this is helpfull for you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815551/how-to-do-this-in-laravel-subquery-where-in

Comment: Please edit your question exactly what kind of result you need using subquery

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is how you call the select method

You can check the documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#select-statements

Though I'm not sure about your expected result, I assume that you are trying to get a specific title for each customer info result. You can use join for that case.
Please follow the documentation here. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#joins

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
$data = DB::table('bm_customercontactinfo')
    ->join(DB::raw("(SELECT tl_titlename, tl_titleid FROM bm_titlelist) as sub"), function($join)
    {
        $join->on("sub.tl_titleid", "=", "bm_customercontactinfo.title_id");
    })
    ->select("bm_customercontactinfo.*", "sub.tl_titlename")
    ->get();
```